# write to terminal and read from same line

Tags: c++, qt, cin, cout

*note : I have not found anything on this topic, apologies if this is a duplicate.*

**Require:**

I need a user to view text and input text onto the same line:

e.g.

```
Please enter your name: {user enter's name here}
```

What I currently have is:

```
using namespace std;
//...
cout << "Enter name: " << endl;
QString name = cin.readLine();
```

This displays:

```
Enter name:
{user enters name on next line}
```

**How can I allow input on previous line and read this input?**

Comment: Don't send a `newline` and if the output does not appear, flush it.

Comment: I do not quite follow, could you possibly give an answer with your suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove end of line and flush the output:

```
cout << "Enter name: " ;
cout.flush();
```

Comment: this does not solve it completly, the terminal seems to hang, I had to flush the `cout`, see my update

Answer (score 2):

In C it can be done like this, without printing a `newline`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char name[100];
    printf("Enter name: ");               // no newline
    fflush(stdout);                       // ensure text is printed
    fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just figured it out, I'll update my question with my specific solution, the flush did work, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**This is my specific solution**

and thanks to comment of "Weather Jane" regarding flush and removing the newline (which is `endl`)

```
using namespace std;
//...
cout << "Enter name: ";
cout.flush();
QString name = cin.readLine();
```

If I just removed the `endl`, the terminal would hang, thus calling the `cout.flush()` solved this "hang" issue.

Hope this helps someone else